# No file selected error not showing in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a defined a file upload field but the issue here is I am able to submit the form even if I have not selected a file. Please help me figure out how to through an error that no file is selected on clicking on the submit button if no file is selected. I am using vuetify version 1.0.

```
<template>
 <v-form :model='agency' ref='AgencyForm'>
  <div class="vue-file-wrapper">
   <input
    type="file"
    ref="file"
    name="vue-file-input"
    required
    :rules='uploadDocument'
    @change="onFileSelected"
    >
  </div>
  <v-btn @click.prevent='submit'>Save</v-btn>
 </v-form>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  props: ['agency'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      filename: '',
      uploadDocument: [
        value => !!value || 'Please upload document'
      ],
    }
  }
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) {
        return;
      }
      this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage(file) {
      var fileReader = new FileReader(),
        that = this;

      fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        that.agency.document = event.target.result;
        that.agency.filename = file.name;
        that.filename = file.name;
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    submit() {
      if (this.$refs.AgencyForm.validate()) {
       this.$axios.put('/agency.json', { agency: this.agency })
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, please could you show your vue devtools value for `filename`? Does your axios put request fire onsubmit?

Comment: @Tony if no file is selected then the file name is null

Comment: I want to know if the only problem is that the error message is not showing. Does the form send the axios put request when there's no file selected?

Comment: @Tony I checked the put axios request is sent with no file selected.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some issues with your current implementation. Firstly, you are directly mutating a prop `agency`, which isn't a good practice. Also, you aren't waiting for your axios request to complete on submission.

However, for your current situation of not having an error thrown when no file is selected on clicking on the submit button, I think the issue is a syntax problem.

You currently have

```js
 <div class="vue-file-wrapper">
   <input
    type="file"
    ref="file"
    name="vue-file-input"
    required
    :rules='uploadDocument'
    @change="onFileSelected"
    >
```

According to the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/), it should be

```js
 <v-file-input 
   :rules="uploadDocument"
   @change="onFileSelected"
  >
 
 </v-file-input>
```

You can then leave the `data` property as it was

```js
data: function () {
    return {
      filename: '',
      uploadDocument: [
        value => !!value || 'Please upload document'
      ],
    }
  }
```

EDIT -- since in Vuetify 1.0.5, there's no support for `v-file-input`, from this Github [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/238), you can do this

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field prepend-icon="attach_file" single-line
    v-model="filename" :label="label" :required="required"
    @click.native="onFocus"
    :disabled="disabled" ref="fileTextField"></v-text-field>

    <input type="file" :accept="accept" :multiple="false"
     ref="file" @change="onFileSelected">
   </div>
 </template>
```

Your data property now becomes

```js
data: function () {
    return {
      filename: '',
      uploadDocument: [
        value => !!value || 'Please upload document'
      ],
      errors: {
        file: ''
      }
    }
 }
```

You can then style the text field using SCSS/CSS to be below the file input field or something.

One thing is for sure, the `rules` prop will not work on a `input` element because it's reserved for `vuetify` specific elements.

It won't be triggered by `this.$refs.AgencyForm.validate()` for that very reason. You will have to write custom validation

Maybe something along the lines of

```js
 methods: {
  validateFile(file) {
    if (!file.name) {
      errors.file = 'Please select a file';
    } else {
       errors.file = '';
    }
  }
  atLeastOneErrorExists(errors) {
    return Object.values(errors).some(error => error.length > 0)
  }
  onFileSelected(event) {
    var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length) {
      return;
    }
    var file = files[0];
    this.filename = file.name;
   
     this.createImage(files[0]);
 
  },
  submit() {
     this.validateFile(this.filename);
    if (this.atLeastOneErrorExists(this.errors)) {
      this.$axios.put('/agency.json', { agency: this.agency })
    }
  }
 }
```

In your template, you can simulate the error message of Vuetify by styling a `p` tag that looks similar to Vuetify error messages

Something like

```html
<div class="vue-file-wrapper">
   ...
   <input
    ...
    >
    <p class="custom-error-class">{{errors.file}}</p> // custom error message
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi, @user12763413 please disregard my previous answer. I have updated it. Check if this helps you.

Comment: I am using Vuetify version 1.0.5
v-file-input is not supported in it.

Comment: Hi, @user12763413. Noted. I have updated my answer.